# Разница в параметрах контролера в MVC 5 и Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Имеется следующий код

```
public string Post(string value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Почему такой код в контролере MVC 5 отлично обрабатывается, а в контролере Web Api 2 я получаю ошибку `405 Method Not Allowed` со следующим HttpBody `{"Message":"Запрошенный ресурс не поддерживает HTTP-метод \"POST\"."}`? Что именно и почему вызывает такое разное поведение?

**UPD**

Я не прошу подсказать как сделать так, чтоб заработало - я знаю: надо либо принимать не `string`, а DTO, либо перед параметром поставить `[FromBody]` и в теле запроса передавать `=value`. Меня именно интересует вопрос выше

Comment: это проблема с сервером: [405 method not allowed web api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api)

Comment: А какой запрос вы отправляете GET или POST? Для WebApi методы с именами Get, Post, Delete (и вроде бы Put) считаются по умолчанию помеченными соответствующим аттрибутом (HttpGetAttribute, HttpPostAttribute и т.д)

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, да, Post, конечно

Comment: Если вы портировали код с MVC в WebApi, то проверьте этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api#answer-21999235

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, нет, причина не в этом

Comment: @Qutrix в таком случае добавьте код контроллера и конфигурации.

Comment: @Qutrix еще вопрос, а вы делаете запрос из fiddler/postman или из браузера (если из браузера и сайт и api на разных доменах, то возможно банально cors), но без деталей сказать сложно.

Comment: В нашем проекте без атрибута `[Route]` метод не считается, даже если он публичный.

Comment: @Qutrix, смотрели ответы по ссылке в моем первом комментарии?

Comment: @Grundy, не очень понял к чему этот вопрос-ответ: там же парень просто перепутал Post и Put, не? Да и проблема не в сервере же: я писал, что знаю как решить, проблема пока что в моем непонимании в разнице поведения mvc и webapi

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что web api и mvc используют разные каналы обработки запроса, и для web api может быть просто не разрешен post запрос, именно из-за этого сервер возвращает ответ 405: метод не разрешен.

Comment: @Grundy, не очень понимаю к чему Вы ведете, но в любом случае iis стоит один и тот же, и он не знает: этот запрос направлен к mvc или к api. С mvc все работает прекрасно. Или под "сервером"  я что-то не то понял?

Comment: @Qutrix, зато знает твое приложение, которое запущено на этом iis

Comment: @Grundy, тогда не понимаю почему Вы говорите, что это проблема с сервером

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46689/discussion-between-grundy-and-qutrix).

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, проверяю через fiddler, код конфигурации и контролера - все стандартное: создаете проект asp.net, выбираете шаблон web api, заменяете метод Post из контролера на тот, что в вопросе и получите то же самое

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, это странно, потому что должен бы. В моем случае можно просто заменить параметр на complex type и все будет работать без [Route]

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value
>   from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>   bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>   and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>   a string. (More about type converters later.) For complex types, Web
>   API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type
>   formatter.

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения на _русском языке_, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Это лишь половина ответа, меня по большей части интересует вторая половина моего вопроса: почему разработчики решили сделать разное поведение для двух родственных технологий? Этому же должна быть причина

Comment: Точно сложно ответить. Скорее всего, чтобы ускорить парсинг модели. Для ApiController сделали свою реализацию IActionValueBinder. https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib есть реализация IActionValueBinder в стиле mvc

Comment: WebApi делали позже MVC, поэтому сделали отдельную имплементацию. В ASP.NET Core сделали как раз одну имплементацию для MVC и WebApi. Ответ очень простой - так исторически сложилось, плюс не хотели ломать обратную совместимость.

Comment: @zayats, интересный гитхабчик, как я понял, поддерживается энтузиастами? И почему решили ускорить web api, и не ускорили mvc?)

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, не проще (и логичнее) было бы взять уже готовую имплементацию? И о какой обратной совместимости Вы говорили?

Comment: @Qutrix в изначальной имплементации mvc много того, что не нужно для webapi (например контроллеры уже имеют в себе возможность возвращать view, action result, javascritp result). Дале, webapi вы можете захостить где угодно, хоть в консольке, хоть в сервисе и они не зависят от views, а mvc зависит.
Обратная совместимость - возможность перейти с mvc3 на mvc4 и 5 например, не переписывая приложение.

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, я и не говорю весь mvc копировать, а только ValueBinder, который и там, и там выполняет одну и ту же функцию

Answer (score -3):

Проблема с заголовками запроса. Либо возвращайте json или поменяйте заголовок на text/plain

Comment: во-первых, не решается
во-вторых, что значит "возвращайте json"?
в-третьих, "поменяйте заголовок на text/plain" - так бывает, что не всегда я (всегда не я) устанавливаю правила игры (заголовки)

Comment: "так бывает, что не всегда я (всегда не я) устанавливаю правила игры" - на самом деле, т.к. вы разрабатываете api, то вы диктуете как клиенты должны с ним работать, а не наоборот.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, но я хочу чтоб клиентам было удобно и они могли выбирать тот способ, который им проще/лучше/более приемлемый, разве это плохо? Мне кажется, именно клиенты устанавливают правила игры, потому что, если это сделаю не я, это сделает кто-то другой

Comment: @Qutrix просто делайте api по стандартам. Пользователям нравится именно это.

Comment: @VadimSentyaev, разный ContentType - это шаг в сторону от api стандарта?